# How do we add custom rows using in power bi based on specific string in a column

Tags: powerbi

Need suggestions how do we create rows to existing table which is pulled in Power BI through direct query. For instance I have Emp Table with a Column which contains coma separated activities by Students like Reporting,Analysing,Troubleshooting (These are just . I am trying to create a measure to add rows for each activity so that I can display activity matric in Pie Chart.

Comment: An example would be super handy. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually got answer to my question, used split  Column by Delimiter option and instead of column I picked the option Row.

Comment: FYI, that’s M code not DAX in the query editor.

Comment: You are right I agree with you. I could not upload image to show options.